# Is Google smart enough to understand article and comment separately on WordPress blog?

Tags: seo, wordpress, comments

One of my client's site totally depends on the comments. It is something like a Q/A site. Users ask questions, answers are given using WordPress default comment system. So the most important content is comments.

But if Google gives separate values for content part and comment part, it is a problem for the client. I want to force Google to take comments also as content / article part.

What can I do for it?

Comment: Google can understand the difference between content and a comment section. Google does not like comment sections primarily because it is often spammed and does not add value or skews search results. I do not believe that search matches are made against comment sections and has not for a long time. It may be possible to configure the comment section to be included into the content. I have not researched this. Another thought would be to update the content to address comments of value. That may be your best answer. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Google indexes comments from a typical WordPress blog and shows them in search results.   That is easy to prove: [Google search for blog comments](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=li:1&num=30&q="really+important+and+reinforced+thoughts")

Comment: Another reason to leave those pingbacks and trackbacks out of the comment feed...

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I stand corrected. There has been contention over the years regarding comments, however, for the final word, I guess it depends upon the comments and the value given perhaps even on the site itself. Perhaps not. Since I do not do the whole blog thing, afterall I hate the term, I have not kept up on the subject. Thanks for sharing! Cheers!!